# Export dataframe with Google Drive API

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

I would like to export my dataframe (`xlsx` format) to my Google Drive with their Google Drive API. I have my API enabled and the credentials exported as `json`.

Is there a way to do export the dataframe directly without saving the dataframe locally?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `my dataframe (xlsx format)`. You want to upload a XLSX data to Google Drive as a XLSX file? Can you provide more information?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. The aim would be to export the dateframe as an xlsx format to Google Drive. However during this time, I found a different alternative by creating a Google Spreadsheet and insert the values to that Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.